# Converst trigonometrical sum in product

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm starting to work with some trigonometrical properties and I got the following problem:

Convert the following sum into a product:
$\cos{x} + \cos{3x} + \cos{5x} + \cos{7x}$

Using the property with states: $\cos{\alpha} + \cos{\beta} = 2 \times \cos{\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}} \times \cos{\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2}}$.

I got:

$2 \times \cos^2{2x} + 2 \times \cos{6x} \times \cos{x}$

How to proceed now ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas,

$$\cos x+\cos7x=2\cos3x\cos4x$$ and $$\cos3x+\cos5x=2\cos x\cos4x$$

Taking out $2\cos4x,$  $$\cos x+\cos3x=?$$