# Trigonometric series sum proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

So, how do I prove that this trigonometric sum equals to zero?

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \cos \left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right) = 0$$

Comment: That's not true, @Brad, if $n$ is odd.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Answer the following questions: What are the roots of $x^n-1=0$? What are the real parts? How can you find the sum of roots of a given polynomial equation by looking at the coefficients?

Comment: Well, lol, actually I tried to solve exactly this problem, but I thought that it would be better to prove that the sum of all the  roots of this equation(over Complex numbers) equals to zero using De Moivre's formula and...failed

Comment: And, yeah, I know that trick with Vieta's theorem, yet for me this method seems to be more elegant

Comment: You can factorize any complex polynomial of degree $n$ in this way: $(x-r_1)\cdots (x-r_n)=0$. So the sum of $r_i$'s has something to do with the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Write 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \cos \left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \operatorname{Re}\!\left(e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{n}}\right) = \operatorname{Re}\!\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{n}}\right)$$
and recall that for any $x\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} x^k = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}.
$$