# Trigonometry involving usage of series

Tags: trigonometry

What is the value of $[\cos(\pi)/2n + 1] + [\cos(3\pi)/2n + 1] + \cos(5\pi)/2n + 1]$ ..... upto $'n'$ terms equals?

Can anyone, please solve this question for me?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that $\cos(k\pi)=-1$, for all odd values of $k$, the summation reduces to 
$$ [\frac{-1}{2n}+1]+[\frac{-1}{2n}+1]+... \text{upto 'n' terms}$$
which equals
$$ n(\frac{-1}{2n}+1) = -\frac{1}{2}+n$$