# sum of a special sequence of trig-function

Tags: trigonometry

How to simply this sum?
$\cos\theta+\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+\cos\frac{\theta}{2^2}+\dots+\cos\frac{\theta}{2^n}$.
What about the $\sin$ function case?

I tried to use double angle formula for cosine. But I couldn't even simply the sum of the first two terms. I think this kind of formula can be very tricky. If you give me the final answer, then I can prove it by induction. It is hard to guess the final answer.

I think this is a kind of math Olympics problem.

Comment: What have you done till now

Comment: @Rememberme I tried to use double angle formula for cos. But I couldn't even simply the sum of the first two terms. I think this kind of formula can be very tricky. If you give me the final answer, then I can prove it by induction. It is hard to guess the final answer.

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910670/naive-proof-that-sum-n-1n-1-cos2-pi-fracnn-1

Comment: @cgiovanardi Thanks. However, the angles in that problem form an arithmetic progression, angles in my problem form a geometric series.