# Simplifying a summation involving "cos".

Tags: trigonometry

$\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\cos ^{2}\left ( \frac{r\pi }{n} \right )$

How can I simplify this summation when I do not know whether "n" is odd or even?

Comment: You can use the identity $\cos^2{x}=\dfrac{1+\cos{2x}}{2}$

Comment: Then use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Is there any other way to solve this question without using the sum of cos of angles in an AP formula? Could we solve it by just proper pairing and then use $sin^2 x + cos^2 x =1$ ?

Comment: @Niharika, Please find my answer

Answer (score 2):

If $\displaystyle S=\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\cos ^2\left ( \frac{r\pi }n \right )$

$\displaystyle 2S=\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}[1+\cos \frac{2r\pi }n ]=n-1+\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\cos \frac{2r\pi }n=n-1-1+\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\cos \frac{2r\pi }n$

Now if $\displaystyle\cos(nx)=1,nx=2m\pi$ where  $m$ is any integer

$\displaystyle x=\frac{2m\pi}n$ where $0\le m\le n-1$

Now using the pattern [here](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/trigonometry/multipleAngles.htm),  $\displaystyle\cos(nx)=2^{n-1}\cos^nx+0\cdot\cos^{n-1}x\cdots=0$

If we set $\cos(nx)=1,$  the roots of $\displaystyle2^{n-1}\cos^nx+0\cdot\cos^{n-1}x\cdots-1=0$ are  $\displaystyle\cos\frac{2m\pi}n$ where $0\le m\le n-1$

So, using Vieta's formula, $\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2m\pi}n=\frac0{2^{n-1}}$