# Theorem of the convergence of the series of fourier!

Tags: fourier-series, education

During the demonstration of the theorem of the convergence of the series of fourier, my teacher wrote :$$  \frac{1}{2}+ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos(ky)=\frac{\sin((n+\frac{1}{2})y)}{2\sin(\frac{y}{2})} $$

he doesn't explain how to get this for the lack of time, I'm curious so I tried alone, without success.
How I can get this equality?

Comment: No wonder you couldn't do it on your own. It is quite hard if you don't know the trick (see my answer).

Comment: This article on the [Dirichlet Kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) might help.

Comment: @malloc,  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Very* briefly: Write $$\cos(ky)=\frac{e^{iky}+e^{-iky}}{2}$$
and use the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series.

**Edit:** To amplify on that a little bit, you can now rearrange the sum on the left to
$$\frac12\sum_{k=-n}^n e^{iky}.$$

**Edit 2:** To sum the above, write it as
$$\frac12e^{-iny}\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^{2n} e^{ijy}}
  =\frac12e^{-iny}\color{blue}{\frac{1-e^{i(2n+1)y}}{1-e^{ijy}}}
   \cdot\color{green}{\frac{e^{-iy/2}}{e^{-iy/2}}}
  =\frac12\frac{e^{-i(n+1/2)y}-e^{i(n+1/2)y}}{e^{-iy/2}-e^{iy/2}}
  =\frac12\frac{\sin((n+1/2)y)}{\sin(y/2)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides by $2\sin(\dfrac{y}{2})$ and remark that

$2\sin(\dfrac{y}{2})\cos(ky) = \sin(\dfrac{2k+1}{2}y) - \sin(\dfrac{2k-1}{2}y)$

Comment: I'll give that answer a +1 for avoidance of the complex exponential function. If you *do* know the complex exponential, however, that is easier to understand.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Yeah I agree using complex number is more simple.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen can you write the complex notation for a more complete answer?

Comment: Okay, I did that, then noticed that the question was closed as a duplicate. I wasn't too sure if the software would accept the edit under these circumstances, but it did. I won't edit it further, though.