# Write $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \cos(k \pi / 6)$ in form $a+bi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

I have to write $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \cos(k \pi / 6)$ in form: $a+bi$.

I think I should consider $z=\cos(k \pi / 6)+i\sin(k \pi / 6)$ and also use the fact that $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ if $|x|<1$

But i don't know if thats correct and how can I transform this.

Comment: See  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression. But $$|e^{ia}|=1\not<1$$ So, we can not apply http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series

Comment: Sure you are not asked about $$\sum_kr^k\cos(k\pi/6)$$ instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos\frac{k\pi}6=\begin{cases}1&\;,\;\;k=0,12,24,\ldots=0\pmod{12}\\
\frac{\sqrt3}2&\;,\;\;k=1,11,13,23,\ldots=1,11\pmod{12}\\
\frac12&\;,\;\;k=2,10,14,22,\ldots=2,10\pmod{12}\\etc.\end{cases}$$

You can fill up the lines missing in "*etc.*"...and thus the series cannot possibly converge (why?)

Comment: but the quesitonw as if it can be written in form $a+ib$ and how

Comment: The series doesn't converge, @luka5z: it is not a number *at all*. We cannot express it neither as $\;a+bi\;$ nor as any other way *numbers* can be expressed.

Comment: Ok thanks! Youre right

Answer (score 1):

You want divergent summation of real numbers written a complex number. Perhaps the goal of the exercise is to check whether this sum is convergent?

If this is the case, some hints:

- complete your summation with $i\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin(k\pi/6) $, you want the real part of this new summation.
- Remember that $cis(kx) = cis(x)^k$
- Observe that the summation can't converge because $cis(x)^n$ diverges

Comment: what is this cis?

Comment: [notation](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Cis_%CE%B8) for $\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$