# calculate for any natural number n $\cos(2\pi/(2n+1))+\cos(4\pi/(2n+1))+\cdots+\cos(2n\pi/(2n+1))$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

How to calculate for any natural number? 
$$\cos\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{2n+1}\bigg)+\cos\bigg(\frac{4\pi}{2n+1}\bigg)+\cdots+\cos\bigg(\frac{2n\pi}{2n+1}\bigg)$$

Comment: It's the real part of a geometric sum.

Comment: @MariaZet,  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Answer (score 2):

This is the real part of
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^ne^{2\pi ik/(2n+1)}
&=e^{2\pi i/(2n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{2\pi ik/(2n+1)}\\
&=e^{2\pi i/(2n+1)}\frac{1-e^{2\pi in/(2n+1)}}{1-e^{2\pi i/(2n+1)}}\\
&=e^{\pi i(n+1)/(2n+1)}\frac{e^{\pi in/(2n+1)}-e^{-\pi in/(2n+1)}}{e^{\pi i/(2n+1)}-e^{-\pi i/(2n+1)}}\\
&=\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi(n+1)}{2n+1}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi (n+1)}{2n+1}\right)\right)\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2n+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n+1}\right)}
\end{align}
$$
Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\cos\left(\frac{\pi(n+1)}{2n+1}\right)\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2n+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n+1}\right)}
&=\frac{\cos\left(\pi-\frac{\pi n}{2n+1}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2n+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n+1}\right)}\\
&=\frac{-\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{2n+1}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2n+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n+1}\right)}\\
&=-\frac12\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{2n+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n+1}\right)}\\
&=-\frac12\frac{\sin\left(\pi-\frac{\pi}{2n+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n+1}\right)}\\
&=-\frac12\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n+1}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n+1}\right)}\\
&=-\frac12
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos(kx) & = \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\sin((k+1)x)-\sin((k-1)x)}{2 \sin(x)} = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \dfrac{\sin(kx)}{2\sin(x)} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{\sin(kx)}{2\sin(x)}\\
& = \dfrac{\sin((n+1)x)+\sin(nx)- \sin(x)}{2\sin(x)}
\end{align}