# De Moivre's theorem:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Could someone help me to expand and express:

$$ 
\sum_{k=0}^N \cos(k\theta)
$$

And:

$$ 
\sum_{k=0}^N \sin(k\theta)
$$

In terms of $$\cos\theta/2$$ and $$\sin\theta/2$$

Using De Moivre's theorem:$$(\cos\theta + i \sin \theta)^N=\cos N\theta+i\sin N\theta$$

I'm still learning series and still not very good at them, so I need help, thanks!

Comment: The guy's name is De Moivre.

Comment: Sorry for the typo

Comment: That summation is meaningless

Comment: It's an exercise in the book I'm reading

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Comment: Corrected the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may write
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{N} \cos (k\theta)&=\Re \sum_{k=0}^{N} e^{ik\theta}\\\\
&=\Re\left( \frac{e^{i(N+1)\theta}-1}{e^{i\theta}-1}\right)\\\\
&=\Re\left( \frac{e^{i(N+1)\theta/2}\left(e^{i(N+1)\theta/2}-e^{-i(N+1)\theta/2}\right)}{e^{i\theta/2}\left(e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2}\right)}\right)\\\\
&=\Re\left( e^{iN\theta/2}\frac{\sin(N\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)}\right)\\\\
&=\Re\left( \left(\cos (N\theta/2)+i\sin (N\theta/2)\right)\frac{\sin(N\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\sin(N\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)}\cos (N\theta/2)\\\\
&=\frac{\sin(N\theta)}{2\sin(\theta/2)}
\end{align}
$$ You easily obtain
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N} \sin (k\theta).
$$

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is a mistake in the solution, being $$(exp(i(N+1)Theta/2)-exp(-i(N+1)Theta/2))/2i$$ equal to $$sin(N+1)Theta/2$$