# Showing that $\cos({\pi\over 11}) + \cos({3\pi\over 11}) + \cos({5\pi\over 11}) + \cos({7\pi\over 11}) +\cos({9\pi\over 11}) = {1\over 2}$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I'm trying to understand [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1105247/822508) proof of the theorem:

$$\cos({\pi\over 11}) + \cos({3\pi\over 11}) + \cos({5\pi\over 11}) + \cos({7\pi\over 11})+ \cos({9\pi\over 11}) = {1\over 2}$$

I'll recreate it briefly here.

> Consider the sum:
>
> $$S_1 = \cos({\pi\over 11}) + \cos({3\pi\over 11}) + \cos({5\pi\over
>  11}) + \cos({7\pi\over 11}) + \cos({9\pi\over 11})$$
>
> As $\cos$ is an even function, we may re-express this as:
>
> $$S_2 =\cos({-\pi\over 11}) + \cos({-3\pi\over 11}) + \cos({-5\pi\over
>  11}) + \cos({-7\pi\over 11}) + \cos({-9\pi\over 11})$$
>
> Together with:
>
> $$\cos({11\pi\over 11}) = \cos\pi = -1$$
>
> These give the real part of all $11$ eleventh roots of unity, which sum to $0$.
>
> $$S_1 + S_2 - 1 = 0 = 2S_1 -1$$
>
> Hence $S_1 = 1/2$

There are a couple key steps I don't follow. Firstly, how are $\cos({\pi\over 11}), \cos({3\pi\over 11}), \ldots \cos({-9\pi\over 11})$ found to correspond to the eleventh roots of unity? In general, the real part $n^{th}$ roots of unity are given by:

$$\cos({2\pi k \over n})\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; k = 0,1,\ldots n-1$$

In the case $n=11$, this yields:

$$\cos(0), \;\cos({2\pi \over 11}), \;\cos({4\pi k \over n}), \ldots\;\cos({20\pi k \over n})$$

Further, the expression within the cosine is never negative. How, then, do $\cos({-\pi\over 11}), \ldots$ also correspond to roots of unity?

Comment: Is there a + sign between the last two cosines?

Comment: @Andrei Yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: They're actually $-1$ times the (real parts of the) eleventh roots of unity. Since those will add up to $0$ anyway, it doesn't really matter. Note that $\cos \frac{9\pi}{11} = -\cos \frac{2\pi}{11}, \cos \frac{7\pi}{11} = -\cos \frac{4\pi}{11}$, etc, and $\cos (-\theta) = \cos \theta$, so $S_1 = S_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a mistake in the language. The roots are not roots of unity, but of $-1$. Also the roots of $-1$ are symmetric with respect to the real line in the complex plane. Note that your angles go from $0$ to $\pi$, so you get only half of the roots. To get all the roots you need to add another angle interval of length $\pi$. You can go from $\pi$ to $2\pi$, or, as in this case, from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.