# Are these trigonometry problems correct?

Tags: trigonometry

I have to prove the following trigonometric identities. However, since I can't prove them, I am starting to think they are not correctly stated.

Problem 1:

$$\cos\frac{2π}{3}+\cos\frac{4π}{9}+\cos\frac{6π}{3}+\cos\frac{8π}{9}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Problem 2:

$$\frac{\cot^2\frac{α}{2}-\cot\frac{3α}{2}}{\cos^2\frac{α}{2}\cosα(1+\cot^2\frac{3α}{2})}=8$$

Comment: I suppose that the first problem is $$\cos\frac{2π}{9}+\cos\frac{4π}{9}+\cos\frac{6π}{9}+\cos\frac{8π}{9}=-\frac{1}{2}$$ Typo's probably. The second is not true; typo's again !

Comment: @parkhyeyoo,  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Comment: Why the second is not correct? Can you exaplain??

Answer (score 0):

The first formula is correct, if we *assume* it is a typo.

Problem 1:

$$\cos\frac{2π}{3}+\cos\frac{4π}{3}+\cos\frac{6π}{3}+\cos\frac{8π}{3}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Sum of $n$ angles in $ AP == \dfrac{\sin n \beta/2}{\sin \beta/2} \cos ( Average Angle)$. Here angle is in degrees.

$$ \dfrac{\sin(4\cdot 120/2)}{\sin (120/2)}\cos{300} = -\frac{1}2 $$