# Solve $\sin A +\sin 2A +\sin 3A + \sin 4A = 0$, for $0 \leq A \leq 180$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I've tried using factor formula but still did not manage to get the answer, not sure if factor formula is the right method.

I rearrange to $\sin 4A + \sin 2A + \sin 3A + \sin A = 0$,

and after applying factor formula,

$2 \sin 3A \cos A + 2 \sin 2A \cos A = 0$

$2 \cos A ( \sin 3A + \sin 2A) = 0$

$2 \cos A ( \sin \frac{5}{2} A \cos \frac{1}{2} A) = 0$

Then I'm stuck..

Comment: One of the factors is zero.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341096/cos-2-leftx-right-cos-2-left2x-right-cos-2-left3x-right-frac32

Answer (score 4):

From the point that you stopped

> $$2 \cos A ( \sin \frac{5}{2} A \cos \frac{1}{2} A) = 0$$

$$2\cos(A/2)\cos(A)\sin(\frac{5A}{2})=0 \bigg/:2$$

$$\cos(A/2)\cos(A)\sin(\frac{5A}{2})=0$$

$\cos(A/2)=0\;$ or $\cos(A)=0\;$ or $\sin(\frac{5A}{2})=0$

Comment: I solve and got 0, 90, 144, 180 but im still missing 72(answer sheet shows that 72 is one of the answer).

Can you see if you have 72 as one of your answer?

Comment: The general solution should be: $a_1=n\pi,\;a_2=n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},\;a_3=2n\pi-\frac{4\pi}{5},\;a_ 4=2n\pi-\frac{2 \pi}{5} ,a_5=2n\pi+\frac{2\pi}{5} ,\; n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @ming $72^\circ$ satisfies $\sin\frac{5A}2 = 0$. In fact, the general solution from $\sin\frac{5A}2 = 0$ is
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{5A}2 &= 180^\circ n&n\in\mathbb Z\\
A &= 72^\circ n
\end{align*}$$

Comment: to be honest I actually dont understand what are y'all doing, maybe a little but mostly no.

here's how I approach,

Let basic angle = a

cos A = 0        sin 5/2 A = 0        cos 1/2 A = 0
  a = 90              a = 0                     a = 90

Comment: @ming Then the problem is you have missed $\frac{5A}2 = 180^\circ$ and $\frac{5A}2 = 360^\circ$.

Answer (score 2):

You've done the hard work

Now the product of three multiplicands is zero

so at least one of them must be equal to zero

If $\sin B=0,B=n180^\circ$

If $\cos C=0, C=(2m+1)90^\circ$ where $m,n$ are integers

Answer (score 1):

Had the number of summands been larger, we could employ the method dsecribed in [How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro)

If $\sin\dfrac A2=0,$ given expression holds true

and $\dfrac A2=n180^\circ\iff A=n360^\circ$ where $n$ is any integer

Else $A\ne n360^\circ$ and $\sin A+\sin2A+\sin3A+\sin4A=\cdots=\dfrac{\cos\dfrac A2-\cos\dfrac{9A}2}{\sin\dfrac A2}$

So we need $\cos\dfrac A2-\cos\dfrac{9A}2=0\iff\cos\dfrac{9A}2=\cos\dfrac A2$

$\implies\dfrac{9A}2=360^\circ m\pm\dfrac A2$ where $m$ is any integer, but $A\ne n360^\circ$

Consider the +, - separately

Answer (score 0):

we have, $$\sin A+\sin 2A+\sin 3A+\sin 4A=0$$ $$(\sin A+\sin 3A)+(\sin 2A+\sin 4A)=0$$ $$2\sin\left(\frac{A+3A}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-3A}{2}\right)+2\sin\left(\frac{2A+4A}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{A-3A}{2}\right)=0$$ $$2\sin 2A\cos A+2\sin 3A\cos A=0$$ $$2\cos A(\sin 2A+\sin 3A)=0$$ $$\implies \cos A=0\implies \color{blue}{A=2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}$$ $$\implies \sin 2A+\sin 3A=0\implies \sin 3A=-\sin 2A$$ $$\implies 3A=2n\pi-2A\implies \color{blue}{A=\frac{2n\pi}{5}}$$ Or $$3A=(2n+1)\pi-(-2A)$$ $$\implies \color{blue}{A=(2n+1)\pi}$$ Where, $n$ is any integer.

**Edit**: For $0\leq A\leq 180^\circ$ put $n=0$, $n=1$ & $n=2$ in the solutions, we get the following $$\color{blue}{A\in \left\{0, \frac{2\pi}{5}, \frac{\pi}{2},  \frac{4\pi}{5}, \pi\right\}}$$ or $$\color{blue}{A\in \left\{0^\circ, 72^\circ, 90^\circ, 144^\circ, 180^\circ\right\}}$$

Comment: $$\begin{align*}\sin A + \sin 3A &= 2\sin 2A \color{red}\cos A\\
\sin 2A + \sin 4A &= 2 \sin 3A \color{red}\cos A\end{align*}$$ which is what OP has written.

Comment: @peterwhy: So, could you please explain if there is something wrong in the solution, if you don't mind?

Comment: Then the $5$th line should be
$$\implies \cos A = 0 \implies \color{blue}{A= n\pi + \frac\pi2} $$

Comment: Oh, sorry I couldn't spot the error. you are right. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I actually don't understand what are y'all doing, maybe a little but mostly no.

here's how I approach,

Let basic angle = a

cos A = 0
  a = 90
  **A = 90**

sin 5/2 A = 0 
a = 0
5/2 A = 0, 360
**A = 0, 144**

cos 1/2 A = 0

a = 90

1/2 A = 90

**A = 180**

Therefore, A = 0, 90, 144, 180

But where's the 72 T.T

Comment: Then the problem is you have missed $\frac{5A}2 = 180^\circ$.

Comment: oh my gawd.. thanks so much!