# Prove that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\sin(2n+1)x}{\sin(x)}dx}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $n\ge0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Prove that
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\sin(2n+1)x}{\sin(x)}dx}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ for $n\ge0$

I am not able to proceed with the integral. For the case $k+1$ please guide me through the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not true for $n=0$, did you mean $n\ge1$?

Comment: @AritraDas: Sorry, for the mistake in the question

Comment: For $n=0$ the integrand is $\sin(x)/\sin(x)=1$.  Over an interval of length $\pi/2$, the integral of $1$ is $\pi/2$.  Or not?

Comment: @ForgotALot the question was a bit different back then.

Comment: @ForgotALot I posted a wrong question back then. I am sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{1}{2} + \cos y + \cdots +\cos (ny) = \frac{\sin (n+1/2)y}{2 \sin (y/2)}.
$$
This is a useful identity that can be used to prove the convergence of Fourier series. It is proved by induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not familiar to such. A slight explanation and expansion will be very helpful.

Comment: Put $y=2x$ and insert into your integral.

Comment: May I know what this identity is called for future reference and better understanding.

Comment: look up Dirichlet kernel.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{\sin(x)} = \frac{e^{(2n+1)ix}-e^{-(2n+1)ix}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}e^{2ikx} $$
and for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, 
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{2ikx}\,dx \in i\mathbb{R},$$
but the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{\sin(x)}\,dx$ has to be real, hence it equals the contribute given by $k=0$ only.

Comment: D' Aurizio could you please explain why is K = -n to n

Comment: @WriSav: it is a consequence of $$\frac{z^{m+1}-1}{z-1}=1+z+z^2+\ldots+z^m.$$ Set $m=2n$, $z=e^{ix}$ and rearrange.

Comment: It might be trivial, but I am still not getting it. Sorry !

Comment: Moreover, can't a integral have an imaginary value.

Comment: @WriSav: not the integral of a real function, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$$\sin(m+2)x-\sin mx=2\sin x\cdot\cos(m+1)x$$

So, if $\displaystyle I_m=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\sin mx}{\sin x}dx,$

$$I_{m+2}-I_m=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(m+1)x\ dx=\dfrac2{m+1}\cdot\left\{\sin(m+1)\dfrac\pi2-\sin0\right\}$$

If $\displaystyle m+1$ is even $\displaystyle=2r$(say), $$I_{2r+1}=I_{2r-1}$$

What is $I_1?$

Comment: I didnt understand where did the sinx go in the step I_m+2 - I_m

Comment: @WriSav, Have u noticed $$2\sin x\cdot\cos(m+1)x$$?

Comment: Yes ! I missed that point. Okay! Now it means that I_2m+1 = I_2m-1

Comment: If you please don't mind can you please tell me, what's this identity is called : $\frac{1}{2} + \cos y + \cdots +\cos (ny) = \frac{\sin (n+1/2)y}{2 \sin (y/2)}$ I know this is from a different answer. but I need it now since I have to discuss tomorrow and the person who posted the answer is not online right now..

Comment: @WriSav, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Comment: I_1 = I_3 =I_5 =... I_n = pi/2 only when n is odd.

Comment: @WriSav, And we need $$I_{2n+1}$$ and  $$2n+1$$ is odd for integer $n$ right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39122/discussion-between-wri-sav-and-lab-bhattacharjee).

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
${\large\mbox{With}\ m = 1, 3, 5, \ldots}$:

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sin\pars{mx} \over \sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x} =
\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\expo{\ic mx} - 1 \over
\pars{\expo{\ic x} - \expo{-\ic x}}/\pars{2\ic}}\,\dd x =
\Im\int_{z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic x} \atop {\vphantom{\Large A}0\ <\ x\ <\ \pi/2}}
\quad{z^{m} - 1 \over \pars{z^{2} - 1}/\pars{2\ic z}}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\\[3mm] = &\
2\,\Im\int_{z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic x} \atop {\vphantom{\Large A}0\ <\ x\ <\ \pi/2}}
\quad{1 - z^{m} \over 1 - z^{2}}\,\dd z =
2\,\Im\pars{-\int_{1}^{0}{1 - y^{m}\expo{\ic m\pi/2} \over 1 + y^{2}}\,\ic\,\dd y} =
2\int_{0}^{1}{1 - y^{m}\ \overbrace{\cos\pars{m\pi/2}}^{\ds{=\ 0}\ } \over
1 + y^{2}}\,\dd y
\\[3mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{1}{\dd y \over 1 + y^{2}} = \color{#f00}{{\pi \over 2}}
\end{align}