# Compute $\sum_{k=0}^{180} \cos^22k^\circ $

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to compute the following:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{180} \cos^22k^\circ $$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** 
Observe that for the first quadrant, we have
\begin{align}
&\cos^22^\circ+\cos^24^\circ+\cdots+\cos^288^\circ+\cos^290^\circ\\
&\quad=\cos^22^\circ+\cos^24^\circ+\cdots+\cos^244^\circ
+\sin^244^\circ+\sin^242^\circ+\cdots+\sin^22^\circ+0\\
&\quad=22.
\end{align}

Comment: Well, this one is $22$, not $44$. Then for the final result you must be careful about not counting some of them twice.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{r=0}^{180}\cos^22r^\circ=1+\sum_{r=0}^{179}\cos^22r^\circ$$

$$S=\sum_{r=0}^{179}\cos^22r^\circ$$
$$=\sum_{r=0}^{44}\cos^22r^\circ+\sum_{r=45}^{89}\cos^22r^\circ+\sum_{r=90}^{134}\cos^22r^\circ+\sum_{r=135}^{179}\cos^22r^\circ$$

As $\cos(180^\circ\pm A)=-\cos A,\cos(360^\circ-A)=+\cos A,$

$$S=4\sum_{r=0}^{44}\cos^22r^\circ$$

Finally,
$$\dfrac S2=2\sum_{r=0}^{44}\cos^22r^\circ=\sum_{r=0}^{44}\cos^22r^\circ+\sum_{r=0}^{44}\cos(90-2r)^\circ=45$$

Answer (score 2):

Remark that:

$cos(x+90°) = sin(x)$

And that:

$cos^2(x) + sin^2(x) = 1$

So you can group your terms:

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=0}^{180} cos^2(x.2°) &=  \sum_{x=0}^{44} cos^2(x.2°) \\
                             & + \sum_{x=45}^{89} cos^2(x.2°) \\
                             & + \sum_{x=90}^{134} cos^2(x.2°) \\
                             & + \sum_{x=135}^{179}{cos^2(x.2°)} \\
                             & + cos^2(180.2°) \\
\\
&= \sum_{x=0}^{44}{cos^2(x.2°)+cos^2(x.2°+90°)} \\
& + \sum_{x=90}^{179}{cos^2(x.2°)+cos^2(x.2°+90°)} \\
& + cos^2(360°) \\
\\
&= \sum_{x=0}^{44}{cos^2(x.2°)+sin^2(x.2°)} \\
& + \sum_{x=90}^{134}{cos^2(x.2°)+sin^2(x.2°)} \\
& + 1 \\
\\
&= \sum_{x=0}^{44}{1} \\
& + \sum_{x=90}^{134}{1} \\
& + 1 \\
&= 91
\end{align*}
$$

See the approximate results at [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(x%3D0,+180,+cos(%5Cpi%2F180*2*x)%5E2))

Comment: The answer would be 90.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Can you pinpoint where I missed something in my proof ? The approximate answer is 91 for wolfram alpha too ...

Comment: By solmilkyu's answer,$22*4+2=90$  point is $cos^2(0)=1.$

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Let's call solumilkyu's sum: $S$, then by symetry we know it appears $4$ times, this would sum twice cos²(90) and cos²(270) but these are $0$ so it's not a problem . But this left out the following values: cos²(0), cos²(180) and cos²(360). So you must add $3$ and not $2$ to get the final result.

Comment: Well,that's right.

Answer (score 2):

$$S=\sum_{r=0}^{180}\cos^22r^\circ$$

$$2S=\sum_{r=0}^{180}(1+\cos4r^\circ)=181+\sum_{r=0}^{180}\cos4r^\circ$$

Using [$\sum \cos$ when angles are in arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression),

$$\sum_{r=0}^{180}\cos4r^\circ=\dfrac{\cos(2\cdot180^\circ)\sin(2\cdot181^\circ)}{\sin2^\circ}=+1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$S(n)=\cos^2 0°+ \cos^2 2°+ \cos^2 4°+....+ \cos^2 2n°$$

1) $\cos^2 \alpha =\frac{1+\cos 2 \alpha}2$. Then 
$$S=\frac{1+n+\left(\cos 4°+ \cos 8°+....+ \cos 4n°\right)}2$$

2) Let $S_1=\cos a_1+ \cos a_2+....+ \cos a_n$, where $(a_n) -$ arithmetical progression ($d\not=2\pi k, k \in \mathbb Z$)

Then 
$$S_1=\frac{\sin\frac{nd}{2}\cdot \cos\frac{2a_1+d(n-1)}2}{\sin \frac d2}$$