# Evaluating $\sum_{k=1}^{10}\left(\sin\frac{2k\pi}{11}+i\cos\frac{2k\pi}{11}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation

> Find the value of $$\sum_{k=1}^{10}\left(\sin\frac{2k\pi}{11}+i\cos\frac{2k\pi}{11}\right)$$

I have heard somewhere that this question can be done by $nth$ roots of unity or by vector algebra. But I'm looking for a solution involving just trigonometry. Is it possible to do it with trigonometry and applying almost no knowledge of vectors or $nth$ roots$?$

I have opened the summation and used the formulas of
$$\sin x+\sin2x+\cdots+\sin nx$$
$$\cos x+\cos2x+\cdots+\cos nx$$
But I can't get any further. Also, if there are any other methods (other than I mentioned), I'll appreciate that.

Comment: If you allow geometry, these are all-but-one of the vertices of a regular hendecagon/undecagon centred at the origin, so by symmetry with that missing point would have a mean of $0+i0$ and so this sum is the negative of that extra point $(0+i1)$ and so is $-i$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1905201/11619) and undoubtedly several earlier threads. Using complex roots of unity is possibly the easiest to comprehend, but whatever. Observe that your sum is missing one term from the sum handled there, and you need to cater for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long comment rather than a solution.
Since $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ and $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$, it holds $\sin(2\pi\frac{k}{11})=-\sin(2\pi\frac{11-k}{11})$ and $\cos(2\pi\frac{k}{11})=\cos(2\pi\frac{11-k}{11})$, whence the sum simplifies to
$$2i\sum_{k=1}^5 \cos\left(2\pi\frac{k}{11}\right).$$

Comment: But it's not finished ! There exists a closed form formula because it is $2i \Re \sum_{k=1}^5 e^{2 k \pi i/11}$ which is the sum of a geometric (finite) series.

Answer (score 2):

By properties of the polar representation of complex numbers, we can see that this is a sum of a geometric sequence. We can define:

$$a_k=\sin(\frac{2\pi k}{11})+i\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{11})=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{2\pi k}{11})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{2\pi k}{11})=e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{2\pi k}{11})}$$

And notice:

$$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{2\pi (k+1)}{11})}}{e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{2\pi k}{11})}}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}-i\frac{\pi}{2}-i\frac{2\pi (k+1)}{11}+i\frac{2\pi k}{11}}=e^{-i \frac{2\pi}{11}}$$

This is a constant, so the sequence is indeed geometric with a commom ratio of $e^{-i \frac{2\pi}{11}}$.

To use the formula for the sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric sequence we would also need to find:

$$a_1=e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{2\pi}{11})}=e^{i\frac{7\pi}{22}}$$

Finally, we can plug everything into the known sum formula:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{10}a_k=\fbox{$\frac{e^{i\frac{7\pi}{22}}(1-e^{-i \frac{10\cdot2\pi}{11}})}{1-e^{-i \frac{2\pi}{11}}}$}$$

And this can obviously be simplified to an expression looking like $a+bi$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\frac{\pi}{11}$ and so let

$$S=\cos2x+\cos4x+\cos6x+\cos8x+\cos10x\implies$$

$$2\cdot\sin x\cdot S=2\sin x\cos2x+2\sin x\cos4x+2\sin x\cos6x+2\sin x\cos8x+2\sin x\cos10x\implies$$

$$2\cdot\sin x\cdot S=\sin3x-\sin x+\sin5x-\sin3x+\sin7x-\sin5x+\sin9x-\sin7x+\sin11x-\sin9x$$

I applied $2\cos A\sin B=\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)$ So,

$$2\cdot\sin x\cdot S=\sin11x-\sin x$$

Undo the substitution, $$\sin11x=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{11}\cdot 11\right)=\sin\pi=0$$

$$2\cdot\sin x\cdot S=0-\sin x \implies$$

$$S=\frac{-\sin x}{2\sin x}
$$
or

$$S=\frac{-1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The crux of the matter is proving that

$\Sigma=[1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+[5]=-1/2,$

where for brevity $[n]$ is used for $\cos(2n\pi/11)$, or (with an eye towards later interpretation)

$[n]\overset{\text{def}}{=}\cos[1(2n\pi/11)].$

Take our expression for the sum

$\Sigma=[1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+[5]$

and multiply by $[1]$ to obtain

$[1]\Sigma=[1][1]+[1][2]+[1][3]+[1][4]+[1][5].$

Use the sum-product relation for cosines

$[m][n]=\frac12([m+n]+[m-n])$

together with the symmetry and periodicity relations

$[n]=[-n]=[11\pm n]$

to express $[1]\Sigma$ as a linear expression in the cosines:

$[1][1]=\frac12([2]+[0])=\frac12+\frac12[2]$

$[1][2]=\frac12([3]+[-1])=\frac12[1]+\frac12[3]$

et cetera, and thence

$[1]\Sigma=\frac12+\frac12[1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+[5].$

Similarly derive expressions for $[2]\Sigma, [3]\Sigma, [4]\Sigma, [5]\Sigma$. Note the nearly symmetrical nature of the results, which for completeness include the $[1]\Sigma$ product derived above:

$[1]\Sigma=\frac12+\frac12[1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+[5]$

$[2]\Sigma=\frac12+[1]+\frac12[2]+[3]+[4]+[5]$

$[3]\Sigma=\frac12+[1]+[2]+\frac12[3]+[4]+[5]$

$[4]\Sigma=\frac12+[1]+[2]+[3]+\frac12[4]+[5]$

$[5]\Sigma=\frac12+[1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+\frac12[5]$

And add everything up:

$([1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+[5])\Sigma=\frac52+\frac92([1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+[5]).$

Now the combinations $[1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+[5]$ can be replaced by $\Sigma$ and we have a **quadratic equation** for $\Sigma$:

$\Sigma^2-\frac92\Sigma-\frac52=0.$

Solving by standard methods gives two candidate roots $\Sigma=-\frac12$ and $\Sigma=5$. The latter is clearly impossible, or more precisely it's the sum we would get if we had chosen to render

$[n]\overset{\text{def}}{=}\cos[\color{blue}{0}(2n\pi/11)].$

instead of the intended

$[n]\overset{\text{def}}{=}\cos[\color{blue}{1}(2n\pi/11)].$

Thus the remaining root $-1/2$ must be the required sum value.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to observe that the expression is just a geometric series $$\sum_{k=1}^{10}z^k$$ where $z=e^{(2\pi /11)i}$. If you prefer to do the real and imaginary parts separately, you could use the forward difference operator $\Delta f(k)=f(k+1)-f(x)$  and $$\sum_{k=a}^b\Delta f(k)=f(b+1)-f(a)$$where$$\cos (k \theta)=\Delta(\sin ((k-1/2)\theta)/(2\cos(\theta /2)))$$  and $\theta=2\pi /11$ with a similar formula for the $\sin$ summation.