# Calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos\left( \frac{2\pi k}{2n+1} \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Calculate the limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos\left( \frac{2\pi k}{2n+1} \right).$$

**Remark:** I need a suggestion, I do not know from what point of view I go along with this exercise

Comment: $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ plus the geometric sum formula.

Comment: Do you know Euler's formula for complex exponentials? If so, you can view this as the real part of a sum of complex exponentials, which is more easily computed.

Comment: See  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$\cos\left( \frac{2\pi k}{2n+1} \right)=\mbox{Re}e^{i \frac{2\pi k}{2n+1}}$$

If you don't know complex exponential, you can also multiply by $\sin$ of half increase:
$$\sin\left( \frac{\pi }{2n+1} \right)$$
and your sum becomes telescopic.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n  \cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{2n+1}\right)=\mathrm{Re}\sum_{k=1}^n  \mathrm{e}^{\frac{2k\pi i}{2n+1}}=\mathrm{Re}\,\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\pi i}{2n+1}}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2n\pi i}{2n+1}}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\pi i}{2n+1}}-1}=\mathrm{Re}\,\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\pi i}{2n+1}}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\pi i}{2n+1}}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{2\pi i}{2n+1}}-1}\to -\frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: In your proof you are using the fact $e^{\frac{2n \pi i}{2n+1}}=e^{\frac{- \pi i}{2n+1}}$. This is not correct, the right thing is $e^{\frac{2n \pi i}{2n+1}}=-e^{\frac{- \pi i}{2n+1}}$.