# Proof of "clear" infinite trigonometric equality.

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I was reading a paper and the author stated: It is clear that,
$cot((1/2) x)sin(nx) = 1+2cos(x)+2cos(2x)+...2cos((n-1)x)+cos(nx)$ it doesn't look like a taylor expansion so how is this true? It is trivial to prove by induction but what do you think the inspiration is? Also, while I am already discussing it: Any formula for $cos(nx)$ or the Tchebyshev polynomials?

The paper by Ramanujan: http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram18.pdf 
see page 3.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/140607) probably answers both your questions