# Can someone confirm my method and answer for this trig problem?

Tags: trigonometry

Find the exact value of:

$$\cos 1^{\circ}+\cos 2^{\circ}+\cos 3^{\circ}+ \ldots +\cos 358^{\circ}+\cos 359^{\circ}$$

I got $0$ as I did this by assigning either a positive or negative $x$ variable for each quadrant. Is this method valid and my answer right?

Comment: If you added $\cos 0$, then your analysis would be correct.  Therefore, the actual value is...?

Comment: That's why you've to be careful when using 'intuitive reasoning'. Better to work out the algebra to verify it. In this case you compare $\cos(x)$ and $\cos(x+180^\circ)$.

Comment: Use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\sum \cos$ when angles are in arithmetic progression](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117114/sum-cos-when-angles-are-in-arithmetic-progression)

Answer (score 19):

Almost. Observe that every term except for $\cos(180^{\circ})$ will cancel out.

Comment: [Simplicity is simpler than complexity.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/25800/276406)  ;)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is $-1$.

My solution uses vector addition (equivalently, complex number addition).

Think of $\cos n^\circ$ as the $x$-coordinate of the point $(\cos n^\circ,\sin n^\circ)$, the point $n$ degrees along the circle. The sum:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{359}(\cos n^\circ,\sin n^\circ)$$
is, therefore, the sum of the vertices of a regular $360$-gon centered at the origin. (Notice that it begins at $n=0$, not $n=1$.)

This sum doesn't change when you rotate it by $1^\circ$ around the origin, since rotating a $360$-gon by $1^\circ$ doesn't change it, and since rotation around the origin is a linear map (the rotation of the sum is the sum of the rotations). The only vector that doesn't change when you rotate it around the origin is the origin itself, $(0,0)$. Therefore, the above sum equals $(0,0)$.

Looking at the $x$-coordinate, we get:
\begin{align}
0&=\cos0^\circ+\cos1^\circ+\dotsb+\cos359^\circ\\
-\cos0^\circ&= \phantom{\cos0^\circ+{}\!}\cos1^\circ+\dotsb+\cos359^\circ\\
-1&= \phantom{\cos0^\circ+{}\!}\cos1^\circ+\dotsb+\cos359^\circ\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Lagrange's trigonometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange.27s_trigonometric_identities) $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\cos(n\theta)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin((N+\frac{1}{2})\theta)}{2\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}$$
Substituting $N=359$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{180}$, you get $$-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin(360-\frac{1}{2})\frac{\pi}{180}}{2\sin(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{180})}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin(2\pi-\frac{\pi}{360})}{2\sin(\frac{\pi}{360})}=-1$$
since $\sin(2\pi-\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: @Brian Tung You are absolutely correct. I will edit the answer. (Should the comments stay, original answer used incorrect, as pointed out by Brian Tung, $\theta=\frac{\pi}{360}$.)

Comment: You can say more than just $\not= 0$; since $\sin(2\pi-\frac{\pi}{360}) = -\sin \frac{\pi}{360}$, we can equate it to $-1$.

Comment: @BrianTung I wasn't going to be so explicit, but since some of the other answers already were, I guess there is no point.

Comment: Perhaps.  I wouldn't necessarily change it for that reason, though.

Answer (score 1):

Almost. Just write
$$\sum_{k=1}^{359}\cos\left ( \frac{2k\pi}{360}\right)=\cos (\pi)+\sum_{k=1}^{179}\cos\left ( \frac{2k\pi}{360}\right)+\sum_{k=181}^{359}\cos\left ( \frac{2k\pi}{360}\right) $$
Grouping in Gauss Sums yields
$$\sum_{k=1}^{179}\cos\left ( \frac{2k\pi}{360}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{89}\cos \left (\frac{2k\pi}{360}\right)+ \cos\left (\pi-\frac{2k\pi}{360}\right)$$
$$\sum_{k=181}^{359}\cos\left ( \frac{2k\pi}{360}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{89}\cos \left (\pi+\frac{2k\pi}{360}\right)+ \cos\left (2\pi-\frac{2k\pi}{360}\right)$$
Each term cancels out because 
$$\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos (\alpha)$$
$$\cos(\pi+\alpha)=-\cos(\alpha)=-\cos(2\pi-\alpha)$$
A proof without words would go like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos 1^{\circ}+\cos 2^{\circ}+\cos 3^{\circ}+ \ldots +\cos 358^{\circ}+\cos 359^{\circ}=$$
$$\tfrac{2\sin0.5^{\circ}\cos 1^{\circ}+2\sin0.5^{\circ}\cos 2^{\circ}+2\sin0.5^{\circ}\cos 3^{\circ}+ \ldots +2\sin0.5^{\circ}\cos 358^{\circ}+2\sin0.5^{\circ}\cos 359^{\circ}}{2\sin0.5^{\circ}}$$
and you'll get it

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: You can now apply one of the trigonometric [product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) to each term in the numerator.  (This is more complicated than @SarahRubenstein's method but it's more obvious what's left after cancelling terms.)